# ng-click inside of a dynamic content not working

Tags: angularjs

I get my html content from external service. I pull that content and display in my website using angular js. Those content have internal links, which is required to pull more data from service. So i need something like

`<a href='#' ng-click='myfunction(arg1,arg2)'>link goes here</a>` ,

which i am able to get along with data from backend. but i get error like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunctionis not defined.
```

This is the way i am displaying the dynamic content after server request

```
 <p ng-bind-html="getSafeHtml(responseDisplayArticle.body)" class="text-justify"></p>

  $scope.getSafeHtml = function(x)
  {
     //return $sce.trustAsHtml(x);
      var decoded = angular.element('<p>').html(x).text();
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);
  };
```

responseDisplayArticle.body has html content with ng-click in it.
How do i get this working.

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: question is not clear enough to answer.

Comment: Ok, I edited your post to reveal the code, but I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: most probably, angular JS have already compiled that is why ng-click is not an registered event here. Use apply(). Need more code.

Comment: Please see code update.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle, so that we can hands on?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller code, you need to expose the function to the scope.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp');
app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  function myfunction(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
  }
  $scope.myfunction = myfunction;
}]);
```

Comment: Correct me, if my answer is wrong. But why somebody does not read the answer, but simply click "-1", 1 minute after the answer has been posted?